# undefined method `model=' for Qt::ListView

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4

I am trying to write an application with Ruby and Qt. I have the following code:

```
list = Qt::ListView.new(window)
mod1 = MyModel.new #MyModel inherits from Qt::AbstractListModel
list.model = mod1 #<< Fails on this line
```

But it fails, telling me:

```
undefined method `model=' for #<Qt::ListView:0x0000000067e300>
```

Yet I see other posts on SO that use model=, and I see the method listed in IRB when I issue `list.public_methods`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is that I wasn't calling `super()` in the `initialize` method of my model.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering it.